# MongoDB 3.2: Create new field in Aggregation Pipeline from Array Elements

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to create a new field in a collection based on elements in an array field.  My syntax is:

```
    db.Accidental_Injuries_Clean.aggregate([{$project:
 {Month: {$arrayElemAt: ["$Dateinfo", 0]}},
{Year: {$arrayElemAt: ["$Dateinfo", 2]}}, 
State: 1, Operations: 1, Place: 1, Killed: 1, 
Injured : 1, ObjectId: 1}}, {$out: "Accidental_Injuries_Cleaner"}]);
```

And this is an example of a document from my collection:

```
     { "_id" : ObjectId("5ac1dff19a91fd53afc379ca"), 
    "State" : "Delaware", "Operations" : "N/A", 
    "Place" : "Newark", "Killed" : 0, "Injured" : 2,
 "Dateinfo" : [ "November", "23,", "2016" ] }
```

When I try the given command, I receive the error:

E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell):1:93

Am I using the correct syntax to find a property of my array?  I tried using "$Dateinfo.0", but gave me the same error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, and thank you all so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were few syntax error in your query just use the following query to get the desired output.

```
db.Accidental_Injuries_Clean.aggregate([
{$project:
 {
     Month: {$arrayElemAt: ["$Dateinfo", 0]},
Year: {$arrayElemAt: ["$Dateinfo", 2]},
State: 1, Operations: 1, Place: 1, Killed: 1, 
Injured : 1, ObjectId: 1
}},
{$out: "Accidental_Injuries_Cleaner"}])
```

Comment: Oops.  Thank you!